# free heap memory of pointer to pointers variable

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, free

I have variables in my code that are pointer to pointer and I don't know what is the size of their allocated memory. How I can free my variables heap memory?
Suppose following variables:

```
int*** a;
int** b;
```

and know what is the code to free possible allocated memory to them?

Comment: how did you allocated them?

Comment: what do you mean by "I don't know what is the size" ... it should be in the m/c alloc routines

Comment: you can call free for how much time you calls malloca/calloc. [look](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12449/Allocating-memory-to-a-Pointer-to-Pointer-variable)

Comment: is really allocated? you know it? possible take address of some..? but anyway free will take care of it.

Comment: I just pass them to a function and it allocate the heap but I don't know what size does it have

Comment: @rezCash so function in which you pass argument it not visible you? but you can free after no use the pointer you  by just passing pointer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you have,

```
int*** a;
int** b;
```

so, you have 3-dimensional a, 2-dimensional b, so you need to allocate 1 dimension at a time.
e.g.

```
a = (int ***) malloc(sizeof(int **) * SIZE1); // presuming SIZE1 predefined
```

then in a loop i running from 0 to SIZE1 -1,
allocate for a[i]. e.g.

```
a[i] = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * SIZE2); // presuming SIZE2 predefined
```

and continue like that.
During deallocation do it reversely, e.g. 
in a loop i running from 0 to SIZE1 -1,

```
free(a[i]);
```

finally, free a as:

```
free(a);
```

Hope you get the idea!

Comment: What if I don't know the size? @DebasishJana

Comment: @rezCash you need to, because, when you allocate space, you need to know how many such items you are allocating, a = (int ***) malloc(sizeof(int **)) will allocate space for one as if SIZE1 = 1

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass pointer to `free` if it is returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.